# Firebase retrieve data Null outside method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I put the below method inside an `onCreate()`, when the app launch it will trigger this method. But when I try to to get `mName` outside the `ValueEventListener()`, it return `null` and the app crashed.

Anyone know why this issue happen?

```
 ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            UserDetails info = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);
            Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(dataSnapshot));

            mName = info.getName();
            **Log.d(TAG, mName); // HERE GET THE NAME**

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    };
    mDatabase.child("Admin")
            .child("Info")
            .child(uid)
            .addValueEventListener(postListener);

    **Log.d(TAG, mName); // HERE GET NULL**
```

Answer (score 2):

As the others have said: all data from the Firebase Database is read asynchronously. It's easiest to see this by adding some more log statements to your code:

```
Log.d(TAG, "Before attaching listener");
mDatabase.child("Admin")
        .child("Info")
        .child(uid)
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Log.d(TAG, "In listener's onDataChange");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
Log.d(TAG, "After attaching listener");
```

Unlike what you may expect, the output of this is:

> Before attaching listener
>
> After attaching listener
>
> Inside listener's onDataChange

The way to deal with the asynchronous behavior is to reframe your problem.

Right now your code is written: first we load the data, then we log it.

If you reframe the problem to: "whenever the data is loaded, we log it", you get code like this:

```
mDatabase.child("Admin")
        .child("Info")
        .child(uid)
        .addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        UserDetails info = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserDetails.class);
        Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(dataSnapshot));

        mName = info.getName();
        Log.d(TAG, mName);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.w(TAG, "getUser:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
    }
});
```

So all code that needs the data, needs to be inside the `onDataChange()`. Alternatively, you can make your own custom callback method and invoke that from `onDataChange()`. But the logic is always the same: the code that needs toe data, is triggered from `onDataChange()` *when the data is available*.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you very much. But this come out another question, how to do i pass the data to another activity on the spot. I've tried to store data using sqlite inside onDataChange method. But to retrieve it, i have to close and reopen the app.

Answer (score 1):

That's because Firebase still didn't retrieve the data yet at the time you do:

```
Log.d(TAG, mName);
```

`mName` is currently null since  this line was executed before Firebase got the data.

To solve this, you have to `Log.d(TAG, mName)` **inside** the `onDataChange` method. Otherwise, it will be `null` as you haven't set the value yet (since Firebase still didn't get the value yet).