# FireBase getUid Coming Back As Null After Returning a Value

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a child using the user's ID. I found the ID when I created a user here and got the userID in the logcat:

```
     final String fullName = findViewByid(R.id.fullName);
     . 
     .    // Other strings declared here
     .
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FirebaseUser newUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        userID = newUserID.getUid();
                        Log.w(TAG, "AuthenticationComplete:true //id:" + userID);
```

Checked the logcat, seen the userID variable. Checked the auth console, and got "authentication complete:true //id:userid".

This is where the problem comes in.

```
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
     .
     .
     .
     });
     Log.w(TAG, "AuthenticationComplete:true //id:" + userID);
     BasicUser newUser = new BasicUser(fullName, uname, userEmail, password, confirmPassword, city, newState, zip, type);
     Log.w(TAG, "idcheck:" + userID);
     **reference.child(userID).setValue(newUser);**
```

I checked my logcat again, I got "authentication complete:true //id:userid"
"idcheck: null".

Things I've tried:

- Changing the child to uname (another String variable). Data was posted into real time database as intended
- Putting "" "" around userID. Not sure what I thought it was going to do but it was worth a shot
- Placing all strings and bottom code in onComplete method

I had it working before but not exactly sure how, so I know it's possible. TIA!

UPDATE:

I made the variables global and not final. It's working as expected now.

```
public class(){
String fullName;
public void signUp(){
     public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
     
     });
     Log.w(TAG, "AuthenticationComplete:true //id:" + userID);
     BasicUser newUser = new BasicUser(fullName, uname, userEmail, password, confirmPassword, city, newState, zip, type);
     Log.w(TAG, "idcheck:" + userID);
     reference.child(userID).setValue(newUser);
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the non-working code in its entirety instead of breaking it up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to access the `userID` outside of the `onComplete` callback, which isn't going to work.

The reason for this is that the authentication happens asynchronously, and by the time that your `reference.child(userID).setValue(newUser)` runs, the `userID = newUserID.getUid()` hasn't run yet. If you run the code in a debugger and place breakpoints on these lines, or add some logging to them, you can most easily see this.

Any code that needs the UID needs to be inside the `onComplete` that gets called when the user sign in is complete, or be called from there.

So:

```
 public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
     if (task.isSuccessful()) {
         FirebaseUser newUserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
         userID = newUserID.getUid();

         BasicUser newUser = new BasicUser(fullName, uname, userEmail, password, confirmPassword, city, newState, zip, type);
         reference.child(userID).setValue(newUser);

         ...
});
```

Also see:

- [getContactsFromFirebase() method return an empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519), which is for the Realtime Database, but deals with the same problem and contain a longer explanation, and examples.
- [Unable to get firebase current user in kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62054762/unable-to-get-firebase-current-user-in-kotlin/62055178#62055178)

Comment: I tried that but I didn't make the variables global. It worked when I did. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So I made my variables global. Slight hiccup. Edits are in the updated post.